# Reemplazar valor de una propiedad de un array de objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un objeto que contiene un array de objetos, con un método que al llamarlo debe actualizar el valor de una propiedad.

El parámetro `oldName` es el valor actual y `newName` es el que debe dejar después de llamar al método.

```js
const inventory = {
    products: [
      { name: "Tablet", price: 460 },
      { name: "Laptop", price: 780 },
      { name: "Cellphone", price: 520 },
      { name: "Desktop", price: 620 },
      { name: "Macbook", price: 820 }
    ],
    updateProductName(oldName, newName) {
        for (const product of this.products) {
            console.log(product.name);
        if(product.name.includes(oldName)) {
          this.products.splice(this.products.indexOf(product),1,newName);
        }
      }
      return `Product ${oldName} is not in inventory!`;
    }
};

console.log(inventory.updateProductName("Macbook", "Macbook Pro"));
console.log(inventory.products);
```

Debería reemplazar Mackbook por Macbook Pro.  Lo reemplaza pero elimina la propiedad price.

Gracias.

Comment: En tu condicional if, pon `product.name = newName;` en vez del `...splice(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es simplemente actualizar el nombre, solo necesitas asignar el nuevo valor a la propiedad `name` asi:

```js
const inventory = {
    products: [
      { name: "Tablet", price: 460 },
      { name: "Laptop", price: 780 },
      { name: "Cellphone", price: 520 },
      { name: "Desktop", price: 620 },
      { name: "Macbook", price: 820 }
    ],
    
    updateProductName(oldName, newName) {
        
        for (const product of this.products) {
            console.log(product.name);
        if(product.name.includes(oldName)) {

          product.name = newName;
          
        }
    
        
      }
      return `Product ${oldName} is not in inventory!`;
}
}

console.log(inventory.updateProductName("Macbook", "Macbook Pro"));
console.log(JSON.stringify(inventory.products));
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución ocupando la función [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const inventory = {
    products: [
      { name: "Tablet", price: 460 },
      { name: "Laptop", price: 780 },
      { name: "Cellphone", price: 520 },
      { name: "Desktop", price: 620 },
      { name: "Macbook", price: 820 }
    ],
    updateProductName(oldName, newName) {
      let product = this.products.find(a=>a.name==oldName);
      if(product){
        product.name = newName;
        return `Se ha actualizado ${oldName} a ${newName}`;
      }
      return `No se ha encontador ${oldName}`;
    }
};

console.log(inventory.updateProductName("Macbook", "Macbook Pro"));
console.log(inventory.products);
```